# Read through json array and pull just the ID into an array

Tags: java, arrays, json

I am trying to write some code to read through a json file and pull just the ID of each item. Some ID's appear more than once, and I have hit a mental road block!

The json file looks like this:

`{
    "tweets": [
{
        "id": "James Davies",
        "date-time": "03/11/14",
        "message": "Finally I'm absorbent like a sponge!",
        "coordinates": [48.99013,1.995392]
    },
]
}`

This is the code I am currently trying to edit.

```
public List<Tweet> insertJsonIntoList(JSONArray array) throws ParseException{
    List<Tweet> tweetList = new ArrayList<>();        

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        Tweet aux = new Tweet(null, null, null, null);
        aux.setId(array.getJSONObject(i).get("id").toString());
}
    return tweetList;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Check [JSON Pointer](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-appsawg-json-pointer-03) which is supported for example by the awesome [Jackson library](https://github.com/fge/jackson-coreutils#json-pointer-1). Extracting JSON value or list of values should be pretty easy with that.

Comment: If possible, I would like to do this with just the default JSON library. Thanks for the suggestion though. Any other ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by *"the default JSON library"*?

Comment: This libary: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json

Comment: So what is the actual problem? Just simplifying the code or using `Set` instead of `List` to get rid of the duplicities?